APIM developer portal test console does not show gateway custom domains
I registered a custom domain for an APIM gateway. In the developer portal's test console, only the custom domain for the gateway is shown and automatically used.
Details: The APIM instance is deployed in internal (vnet) mode. The default gateway domain is only accessible within the vnet (and on-premise network). The custom gateway domain is used for public access and routed through an on-premise firewall. The developer portal is only accessible from the vnet (and on-premise network) and should therefore use the default gateway domain. Like this, we can use the developer portal in a protected vnet environment and protect the public custom gateway domain with more elaborate measures.
I would expect at least to be able to select which gateway domain should be used for the request (if not even choose a default domain other than the default gateway domain)


I registered a custom domain for an APIM gateway. In the developer portal's test console, only the custom domain for the gateway is shown and automatically used.

Yes, Indeed because once you add a custom domain then the default certificate is the certificate issued to the Gateway's custom domain and you will see Default SSL binding is ticked for that custom domain.

The value of Default SSL binding property can't be changed if you have one custom domain. In case of multiple custom domain you can designate the default certificate by selecting the checkbox of Default SSL binding property in portal. Please refer to the MS Doc which says below-

References-
How is the Gateway Url set in Azure APIM with multiple custom domains - Microsoft Q&A.

Thanks for the additional info. How does this impact to the developer portal? If I would have a second custom domain, could I choose in the developer portal which domain should be used? Does it only use the default ssl binding?

You can't change it in developer portal. You need to tick the checkbox of default ssl binding in case of multiple custom domains in portal and then publish the site

Your screenshot says at the very end: "If you do not set the property, the default certificate is the certificate issued to the default Gateway domain hosted at *.azure-api.net."
However I can't uncheck the default ssl binding option for my single custom domain. Is this correct?

Yes, you can't uncheck it for single custom domain.
